# getting no iAd requests or impressions

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad

I have recently added an update to my app that include iAds. When I was testing the ads they were coming up perfectly fine on my phone with apples tester ads. I had the app accepted into the app store yesterday morning and my iAd section shows 'live ads'. However i have not received an requests at all and this leads me to believe that I have done something wrong in my coding even though all test ads are working completely fine.

Comment: How is it that you know there is no request for iad? Does it not show an add in the place holder at all? As far as doing something wrong, I don't think so. Since your app carried the iad code and it was approved you may not have an issue. Is your app live, free or paid? I like to download it and see if it works?

Comment: When I go on the iAd workbench thing it says that I have no requests no impressions or anything...the app is called taptoflap and it is a free app     https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/taptoflap!/id822046723?ls=1&mt=8.  No ads are showing on the app

Comment: Just downloaded your app. Well your right no adds. Post your code for iad or take a look at apple iad suite sample code. And in addition cloning flappy birds , nicely done...:)

Comment: Hahaha I'm new to Xcode and just wanted to get an app out there...I'll post my code when I get home. Don't worry my next one will be original

Comment: Yes! Just looked at the app again and an ad came up!! Apple must have just been a little slow...the iAd report still shows no impression or requests but I'm not worried it's obviously working

Comment: Glad the issue was resolved. I have to add though, cool graphics. Also, nothing is really original anymore so it's all good. I was just making an observation. I think your game is nice and you are on your way. Good luck.:)